# Windows Server 2008 - Local Area Connection disappeared from ip interfaces

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.
Local Area Connection isn't working anymore, the interface exists but it doesn't as an ip interface.

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh int show int

Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        Local Area Connection


C:\Windows\system32>netsh int ip show int

Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  1          50  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
```

If I try to assign an IP Address I get this:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh int ipv4 set address "Local Area Connection" static XX.XX.XX.XX XX.XX.XX.XX XX.XX.XX.XX
Element not found.
```

What happens? Windows has lost network configuration? 
I've also tried to reset ipv4 and ipv6 networking using netsh but still nothing...

Comment: Since you're doing everything via netsh I guess you're dealing with a server core installation? Please open Powershell and post the result of this command:  `Get-WMIObject win32_networkadapter | select * -ExcludeProperty "__*" | format-list`

Comment: @megamorf, The output was huge, I've created a gist: https://gist.github.com/nahime/f7f670fb96aa771aa4d4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally managed to solve the issue. The problem was the network adapter driver. 
I needed to download [DevCon.exe](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/182.how-to-obtain-the-current-version-of-device-console-utility-devcon-exe.aspx) and:

1. List all network adapter installed
2. Find the physical one
3. Delete the driver
4. Rescan system for new devices.

Finally "Local Area Connection" reappeared within the list of ip interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

According to your gist, the adapter is disabled. Try this in PowerShell:

`$adapter = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "NetConnectionID='Local Area Connection'"`

You should have the adapter available as object $adapter; to verify this use:

`Write-Host $adapter.Name`

It should print the name of the physical adapter, "Intel(R) I210...". If you have the correct adapter, use:

`$adapter.Enable()`

Comment: Tried, still same problem and in Get-VmiObject NetEnabled is still False